# Making formula work only when adding to a value

Tags: microsoft-excel, spreadsheet

I am trying to have a number automatically update itself on our inventory spreadsheet (since we seem to forget to do so ourselves)...but I can't seem to get it quite right.

So our inventory process has three steps:

1. Recieve raw product (+B17)
2. Send raw product to sterilization (-B17,+B10)
3. Sell sterile product (-B10)

It took me FOREVER to find this formula for B17...

=0-B10+0

and now when I add to B10 it automatically subtracts from B17 and there's FINALLY no Circular Reference, but now how do I keep B17 from changing when I eventually have to sell the sterile product and subtract from B10?

I also need to know how to go about adding to B17 when we eventually order more raw product again.

[Spreadsheet Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XzofK.png)

Comment: I think having an example with reduced data and a better description of the process and desired output would be helpful. Or if this is reduced as much as it can get, then why is each row important for your calculations? Where does inventory start, how do you decide how many to send to sterilization, and how many do you decide to sell?

Answer (score 0):

**:Caveat:**

I would like to suggest a method based on, "three steps inventory process" used by the OP.

[image]

**How it works:**

- Formula in cell S2:

  `=IF(ISBLANK(O2),"",P2-(Q2+R2))`
- Enter this formula in cell S3, and fill down till needed.

  `=IF(ISBLANK(O3),"",(P3+S2)-(Q3+R3))`

**N.B.**

- You may use formula to get Column Total of, *New Pro Qty*, *New Pro Sold* & *Pro to Ster*, will reflect Month's Inventory for each activity.
- *Adjust cell references in the formula as needed.*

Comment: Hi @danyell723 ,, now check my post, I'm sure this what you were looking for,, in case of any further query, please do reply through comment,,, and if you find that this is working for you then please [Mark it as answer](https://superuser.com/tour) as well Like ☺.

Answer (score 0):

I think the reason you are generating circular formulas is because Excel doesn't do well what you are trying to do (at least not without some tricks). The inherent problem is you are trying to use "cell history", and Excel doesn't keep historic values of a single cell. You can't do *new cell value = old cell value (from the same cell) + new raw stock*. One cell only has one current value. You need more cells to store historic information - which is why @Rajesh's example works like a log book - each row being a new transaction that can calculate like this: *current stock = old stock (in previous row) + new raw stock*.

For example:
Say A1 is the new raw stock with current value 0 (no formula in this cell),
and A2 is the current stock with value 100 (no formula in this cell),
and A3 is the new stock with formula =A1 + A2 with result 100.
Now you type in A1 the number 10 and press enter. A3 will result in 110. The next day you want to add 20 more raw stock. You type 20 in A1 but A3 is only 120 not 130. The problem is A2 has not been updated from 100 to 110. And unfortunately there is no formula you can enter into A2 to update itself based on its past value. A2 cannot be "=A2 + A1" nor can it be "=A3 + A1", cause A3 already depends on A2, and would otherwise require a past value.

So here's the *trick*. What you need is a macro or some VBA code to program an "Add" button on your spreadsheet that will take the result from A3 (110) and copy its value into A2 (overwriting 100), whilst at the same time zeroing out A1 - ready for the next transaction.

Extrapolating, your spreadsheet could look like this:
[image]

Doing this isn't difficult but requires a bit of programming skills. That or use @Rasjesh's solution :)